# Solving $x'(t)=\frac{1}{1+x(t)^2} $

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I am trying to solve ODE : $x'(t)=\frac{1}{1+x(t)^2} $ with initial value $x(0)=x_0$

I could solve $x'(t)=\frac{1}{x(t)^2}$ by seperating variables.

However, $x'(t)=\frac{1}{1+x(t)^2} $ with initial value $x(0)=x_0$ is another problem, which is I am stucked while studying dynamical system of initial value problem on global system.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @WillJagy isn't it arctan(u)+C?

Comment: @WillJagy That doesn't help here. It would work for $x'(t)=1+x(t)^2$

Comment: @jjagmath good point.

Comment: Hint: $\int (u^2+1)du = u^3/3+u+C$

Comment: @jjagmath I already used sepearablity and then how do I deal with $ x+\frac{x^3}{3} = t +C $? $x^3 + x$ is not easy for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** The equation in the title is still separable: Rewriting gives
$$(1 + x^2) \,dx = dt .$$
Integrating gives
$$x + \frac{1}{3} x^3 = t + C .$$

> Solving the particular i.v.p. with $x(0) = 0$ using, e.g., Cardano's formula gives the particular solution $$x^*(t) = \frac{\left(12 t + 4 \sqrt{4 + 9 t^2}\right)^{1 / 3}}{2} - \frac{2}{\left(12 t + 4 \sqrt{4 + 9 t^2}\right)^{1 / 3}} .$$ Since original system is autonomous, the general solution is $x(t) = x^*(t + C),$ and substituting the initial condition in the last display equation before the spoiler gives $C = x_0 + \frac13 x_0^3$.

Comment: Yes that was I did tried, but it was hard to deal with, since $ x+\frac{x^3}{3} = t +C $

Comment: You can solve explicitly for $x$, but as usual solving a cubic yields a messy answer. Probably the form you've written there is the most readable form of the solution. I can add the explicit formula for $x(t)$ if you'd find it helpful.

Comment: Would you please?

Comment: I've added an explicit solution behind the spoiler tag.

Comment: Generally, in problems like this, we leave it as $x+\frac{x^3}{3} = t +C$ and call it an "implicit" solution.

Answer (score 2):

The solution being
$$\frac 13 x^3+x=t+c_1$$ solve the cubic using the hyperbolic method to obtain as a single root since $$\Delta=-3 (t+c_1)^2-\frac{4}{3} <0$$ and,
$$\large\color{blue}{x=2 \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac 3 2 t+c_2
  \right)\right)}$$